# SharePoint online get the Wiki hidden list using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell

Using PNP PowerShell I am trying to get the SharePoint online wiki hidden list and wanted to un-hide.
I have tried following PowerShell scripts to get the hidden list, but it is not getting the Wiki hidden list.

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://Akshay/sites/Teams    
$lst=Get-PnPList
```

In result it is not showing the hidden list, I have found that the Wiki hidden list name is start with "19:"

Appreciate your help to get the list using PowerShell

Answer (score 1):

You could use command `Get-PnPList` to get all lists. Then copy the id of the Wiki hidden list which name starts with "19:"
[image]

After you get the id of the list, you could use the command to unhide this list:

```
set-pnplist -Identity <id of the Wiki hidden list> -Hidden $false
```

Comment: If my answer helps you, you could accept it as answer :)